# How to give upper case letters a value of two and white space a value of 1 to add to string length and prints out last 12 letters in the string java

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I need to write a method that gives the value of 2 for uppercase letters, the value of 1 for lower case, and a value of 1 for spaces and also add them to my string length. But it can't print out a value it has to print out the last 12 letters in the string after changing the values of the upper, lower case letters and the spaces

For example:
edcdeeE ddDeeEedcdeeE eddedC <-- if this is the string from the user

eeE eddedC <-- this should be the output

the code below is what I came up with but it just gives me a value of 300 and i don't know why, if someone could help me that would be great!!

```
    int upperCaseCount = 0;
    int whiteSpaceCount = 0;
    for(int c = 0; c < song.length(); c++){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(song.charAt(c)))
        {
            upperCaseCount++;
        }
        else if (song.contains(" "))
        {
            whiteSpaceCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            upperCaseCount = 0;
            whiteSpaceCount = 0;
        }

        String whiteSpaceCountString = String.valueOf(whiteSpaceCount);
        String upperCaseCountString = String.valueOf(upperCaseCount);
        song = song.length() + upperCaseCountString + whiteSpaceCountString;
        
    }
    
    //extracts last 12 beats of musical score from song string
    String lastTwelve = " ";
    if(song.length() > 12)
    {
        String songWithNumOfBeats = song;
        lastTwelve = song.substring(songWithNumOfBeats.length()-12);
    }
    else
    {
        lastTwelve = song;
    }
    System.out.println(lastTwelve);
```

Comment: What should happen if there's a two-beat note occupying the 12th and 13th beats back from the end?

Comment: it should return 11 beats

Comment: OK, well there are lots of mistakes in your main loop.  But the most important one is probably the line `song = song.length() + upperCaseCountString + whiteSpaceCountString` - you're replacing your entire song with three numbers concatenated together, and you're doing that as many times as there are characters in the original song.

Comment: oh, so I should take it out of the for loop?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do that step at all.  Either `song` stores the song, or it stores the counts.  Don't change its purpose partway through.

Comment: ok, thanks. how do I add the upperCaseCount and whiteSpaceCount to the string length though, if I shouldn't change it to an int?

Comment: But you're not adding them, you're concatenating them.  Your "300" results from `3 + "0" + "0"`.